# Download file via aws lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have APK files stored and I would like to download them via an AWS lambda function.

Is there a way that the function will resolve with downloading an APK file?

I tried to find a way to change the callback to a response, but i couldn't figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure what you want to achieve, but a lambda function can download files from some accessible web source (the programming language you use needs to be able to do it) and save them temporarily (during lambda execution, not between two calls) or durable upload them to S3 (via AWS SDK).

A lambda function cannot return a file to the caller, just objects/text. What is calling your lambda?

Comment: An android app via http

Comment: Can you just download the file from S3 directly? Lambda could, if at all needed, return you the filename or full download path.